# How to auto import import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.xxx for activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.0, kotlin-android-extensions

Kotlin comes with the powerful feature for view binding using import `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*`. I also know that Android Studio is powerful and flexible for customization. 
[image]
In order to use view binding, we need to include `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_xxx.*` manually after creating the activity.

Is there any way / customization option in Android Studio so that whenever a new activity is created, it imports respective `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_xxx.*` automatically? For example, if I am creating `NewActivity` it should already have `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_new.*`.

Comment: first of all thank for cpp. I am currently using in the projects. For your question i don't think the feature exist. As one can name anything for your layout file. Its good to have name conventions but not mandatory

Comment: It is acceptable if it only handles default activity-layout naming pattern. For example, default layout file name for NewActivity is activity_new. I am aware that android studio allows lots of customizations and so I tried few things on my own but did not find any option. So I thought some *Android Studio Master* on StackOverflow with advance knowledge of customization might help us. Let's wait :)

Comment: Well, I got a shortcut to type this manually. Using a live template and groovy script. Where typing "binder" will auto-complete this import. Groovy takes the file name and convert it into layout file name which is finally inserted in the live template. Even if this is short way, it is manual. I appreciate if someone can automate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio should auto-import it by itself or give you a hint to do so. If it does not already, check and see if the IDE's version of Kotlin matches your project (in gradle) and restart the IDE.

Comment: Yeah. That worked better than the live template. Even if it's not putting import line when activity is created, it suggests the view when we start typing and import afterward.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I am a newb though, so to aid other newbs, I'll add this. Turns out I didn't have all the plugins installed.

The default generated project was:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
```

But needed to also include the extensions bit:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id "kotlin-android-extensions"  // The secret sauce that allows an implicit findViewById.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. For other newbs, I would like to share that synthetic is deprecated. Use viewbinding or databinding if you have good reason to say NO to Jetpack Compose.

Comment: YES! Only saw that recently also. I really put the "crash" in crash course :-P